# Exception thrown: 'HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll when testing over a Lumia 950XL Device

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, template10

I'm builing an app with facebook auth using Azure, now, when i debug my app on my local database on local machine my app works fine when login into my app.

but as soon as I try to test it on my Lumia 950XL sometimes it login in sucessfully and other time i doesnt login at all and show me this:

> Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.AuthenticationDelegatingHandler.CloneHttpRequestMessageAsync'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.AuthenticationDelegatingHandler.d__1..ctor'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.AuthenticationDelegatingHandler.<>n__0'   Step
>   into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.LoggingHandler.SendAsync'   Step into: Stepping
>   over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.LoggingHandler.d__2..ctor'
>   Request: GET,
>   http://quicopc/Ceneam.Backend/tables/Account?$skip=0&$top=25 Step
>   into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'Ceneam.Common.Helpers.LoggingHandler.<>n__0'   15:17:54.3412524
>   Template10 HamburgerMenu.GotFocus  Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
>   name:HamburgerButton  symbol:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FontIcon
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll (this list line 4 times in a row)

now I had debugged my app to my AuthenticationDelegatingHandler class and this is the code where it steps out:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //Clone the request in case we need to use it.
    var clone = await CloneHttpRequestMessageAsync(request);

    //Now do the request
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);/*after pressing the next step it steps out and returns me to my login page again*/

    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        /*The request result in a 401 Unauthorized. We need to do a LoginAsync.
         which will do the Refresh if appropiate, or ask for credentials if not.*/
        var user = await ServiceLocator.Instance.Resolve<ICloudService>().LoginAsync();

        /*Now retry the request with the cloned request. The only thing we have
         to do is replace the X-ZUMO-AUTH header with the new auth token.*/
        clone.Headers.Remove("X-ZUMO-AUTH");
        clone.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        response = await base.SendAsync(clone, cancellationToken);
    }

    return response;
}
```

now I'm not an expert on azure but i cant understand why it only happens in my phone and not in the desktop and the exception doesnt tell me much, and besides strangely as soon as I get at my home It works fine at home it logs in successfully without a problem.
but here at work doesnt.

I had configured the local server for testing purposes and it works great, its just the login in the problem.

Comment: It would be much better if you surrounded the code with a try-catch block and posted the actual exception data

Comment: I had done what you said it says this: [AuthenticationDelegatingHandler] Error on SendAsync Method: An error occurred while sending the request.
with a try-catch block.

Comment: Request: GET, http://quicopc/Ceneam.Backend/tables/Account?$skip=0&$top=25
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
[AuthenticationDelegatingHandler] Error on SendAsync Method: An error occurred while sending the request.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
[Login] Error = Handler did not return a response message.

Comment: EP. Something in in that SendAsync and subsequent ReceiveAsync (guessing) is not waitng for the reply from the server, also that `if statement` is only trapping 1 thing what if there is more to the response such as the error in question you seem to be getting.